# How to get a column of a 2D array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
var array = new[] {new[]{'a', 'b', 'c'}, new[]{'d', 'e', 'f'}, new[]{'g', 'h', 'i'}};

var column = // should be like new[]{'b', 'e', 'h'} given index 1
```

How to do this?

Of course I could create a new list, populate it manually iterating through all the lines in a loop and convert it to an array but Isn't there a more laconic way?

Comment: `array.Select(i => i[1]);` ?

Comment: Yes, I think this is it, @zerkms, thanks. It's unbelievable that I haven't came to this myself (having came from Scala I use mapping like this a lot).

Comment: being a scala guy - indeed, you cannot be forgiven :-)

Comment: What you have here is an array of arrays, of type `char[][]`. If you had a true 2D array, of type `char[,]`, the solution would be different.

Comment: And what would it be, @JeppeStigNielsen. I have always been thinking a multi-dimensional array means an array of arrays.

Comment: With `char[,] arr = { { 'a', 'b', 'c' }, { 'd', 'e', 'f' }, { 'g', 'h', 'i' } };` you could do something like `Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(1)).Select(idx => arr[col, idx]);` where `col` is the zero-based column number. Note for a true 2D array the two indices are separated by a comma.

Comment: Or maybe I swapped the roles of rows and columns, then try `Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(0)).Select(idx => arr[idx, col]);` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**LINQ**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) is your friend.

It's what separates us C# developers from the mere mortals.

```
var array = new[] { new[] { "a", "b", "c" }, new[] { "d", "e", "f" }, new[] { "g", "h", "i" } };

var col1 = array.Select(x => x[1]);

//col1 contains "b", "e" and "h"
```

Comment: Ok, yes, totally misunderstood it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method for that:

```
public static T[] GetColumn<T>(this T[][] source, int columnIndex)
{
    int length = source.Length;

    var values = new T[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
         if(source[i].Length > columnIndex)
            values[i] = source[i][columnIndex];
    }

    return values;
}
```

Then :

```
var column = array.GetColumn(1);
```

This also doesn't throw an `IndexOutOfRange` exception if one of your arrays contains less element than column number.

Comment: The solution `source.Select(x => x[columnIndex])` seen elsewhere in the thread is more beautiful. It could be expanded to `source.Select(x => x != null && x.Length > columnIndex ? x[columnIndex] : default(T))` if you really insist on checking each nested array `x`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen why do you want to return default value when there is no item exists ? if you want to improve `LINQ` solution you can do better: `source.Where(x => x != null && x.Length > columnIndex).Select(x => x[columnIndex]);` BTW, I provide this solution because the LINQ solution is already provided

Comment: I wanted the same behavior as the code of your answer. It makes the "length" of the returned column equal to the `Length` of the outer array, `source.Length`, and the "row numbers" reliable.